# Book (Swift for Dummies) Chapter 4 Exercise: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, null, option-type

I am learning swift, and I am reading the book called "Swift for Dummies" and I tried to follow the author and do the example from the book, but I got an issue in the example from the fourth chapter, can you guys help me.

Error at line 51 in

**MasterViewController.swift**

`newManagedObject.latitude = self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude`

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) in
>   the output windows is shown fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while
>   unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import CoreLocation

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController,
    NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,
    CLLocationManagerDelegate
{

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var lastLocation: CLLocation! = nil



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "insertNewObject:")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
        self.startSignificantChangeUpdates()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
        let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Event

        // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
        // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
        newManagedObject.latitude = self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude
        newManagedObject.longitude = self.lastLocation.coordinate.longitude


        // Save the context.
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
            (segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController).detailItem = object
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as! NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
            context.deleteObject(self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject)

            var error: NSError? = nil
            if !context.save(&error) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Event
        cell.textLabel!.text = "latitude: " + object.latitude.description + " longitude: " + object.longitude.description
    }

    // MARK: - Fetched results controller

    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
             //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
             abort()
        }

        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }    
    var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Delete:
                self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            default:
                return
        }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Delete:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Update:
                self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
            case .Move:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            default:
                return
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    /*
     // Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed.

     func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
         // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
         self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
     */

    // MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate Protocol
    func startSignificantChangeUpdates () {

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined {

            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            self.locationManager.delegate = self

            self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }

    }
    func locationManager (manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]!) {

        self.lastLocation = manager.location
        let eventDate = self.lastLocation.timestamp;
        let howRecent = eventDate.timeIntervalSinceNow;


    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        // need to add code to catch errors
    }

}



import UIKit
import MapKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!


    var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
            if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
                label.text = detail.valueForKey("timeStamp")!.description
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.configureView()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}


import Foundation
import CoreData

class Event: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var latitude: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var longitude: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var timeStamp: NSDate

}


import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let navigationController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! MasterViewController
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.sauer.Locatapp" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1] as! NSURL
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Locatapp", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Locatapp.sqlite")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
            coordinator = nil
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
            error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
           NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator == nil {
            return nil
        }
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
            var error: NSError? = nil
            if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Because value is not there in `self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude`.Check if you are getting any location or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this variable is null

```
self.lastLocation
```

you should call this function

```
func locationManager (manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]!)
```

to init the lastLocation in somewhere. So it wont be null

or you can change

```
var lastLocation: CLLocation! = nil
```

to this

```
var lastLocation: CLLocation? = nil
```

so when running this code

```
newManagedObject.latitude = self.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude
```

it will skip this line because self.lastLocation is null insteand of showing EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error

Comment: The app start but I did not get the location... when I click in + button he close and give this error...

I did what you told me... but I still getting a issue... for now a different one... I changed this line for var lastLocation: CLLocation? = nil
and this one for newManagedObject.latitude = self.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude
and I got this error:  Value of optional type 'CLLocationDegrees?' not unwrapped did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

After this modification... the app do not start anymore.

Comment: did you call the constructor of locationManager before calling this newManagedObject.latitude = self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude?

Comment: I am learning Swift... How can I call the constructor???? maybe I called, but I am not sure because I do not know how to do that...